# Xorg/xrandr - combine screens but keep screen boundaries for Window maximising/placement

Tags: xorg, kde, xrandr, multi-monitor

I have four screens in a 2x2 grid. This all works fine except for one thing - the window list on the taskbar.

What I would like is to have taskbars on the bottom two screens that show all the windows for their screen and the screen above.

KDE is pretty flexible with letting me create multiple taskbars wherever I want, but the only two options are to either show all windows or only windows from the current screen. So I have to choose from these options:

1. A single taskbar on screen that shows all windows
2. Taskbars on both bottom screens both showing all of the windows
3. Individual taskbars on all four screens

I am currently using option 3 but it really doesn't work well for me. I used to have this setup split into two machines with synergy to share the keyboard/mouse and it was much clearer having two taskbars at the bottom instead of four all over the place. I have tested various other desktops and none of them are any better than KDE in this regard.

So my question is - is there a way to configure Xorg/xrandr so that it combines the screens as far as the taskbar is concerned, but without losing the edge hints that help with window placement and maximising?